# How can I get UserName in dot net in my controller file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC application. It uses Windows authentication. I am still running it only from Visual Studio.

I am able to get logged in user name in `*.cshtml` files with `@Environment.UserName`. How can I get same `UserName` in my controllers -> `*.cs` files?

I get an error

> Type name 'UserName' does not exist in the type Environment

Comment: You want to use the `User` property of the current `HttpContext` to determine the user name/identity of the user. `Environment.UserName` will be the user name of the Windows account the _application_ runs as, so is only you when you're doing development. It won't be the logged-in user. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user

Comment: @MartinCostello Or, even shorter, just `User` (`this.User`), which is a shorthand for `HttpContext.User`.

Answer (score 0):

I create two sample projects with windows authentication(.net 3.1 & .net 5.0 ). And I use below code, I can get the usename.

**And my controller just use default HomeController.**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public string GetUserName()
        {
            return Environment.UserName;
        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            // It also works for me
            //return User.Identity.Name;
            return HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
}
```

[image]

[image]